# onEditCell issue with dhtmlxGrid

Tags: grid, cell, editing, dhtmlx

I'm using dhtmlxGrid and as I've found in the docs (https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_oneditcell_event.html) returning "true" confirms the edit, while a value (for example newValue) sets the value.

I've tried both methods, but neither of them works! I can't confirm the edit by "true" nor set the value by "newValue".

Here is my code:

```
myGrid.attachEvent("onEditCell", function(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue){
doOnEdit(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue)
});
...
function doOnEdit(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue){
if (cInd==0 && nValue=="100")
return false
return true
 }
```

Can anybody explain my mistake or is there a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to use the following solution:

```
myGrid.attachEvent("onEditCell", doOnEdit);
...
function doOnEdit(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue){
   if (cInd==0 && nValue=="100")
   return false
   return true
}
```